# Does any of C++ implementation make use of multiple inheritance internally?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, internals

Just a quick silly question:

I was wondering if C++ makes use of the multiple inheritance feature provided by virtual inheritance internally. I know for sure that for the templated implementations such as the Data Structures provided by STL (std::vector <> for instance) cannot make use of such feature, but how about some other objects like streams for instance.

I know that multiple inheritance can be handy in some cases (for cross delegation, for example) but I feel like I should avoid it if C++ devs decided to avoided using such feature in their code.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The standard stream classes.

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Comment: Are you asking about multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance?

Comment: Don't use feelings to make programming decisions. Also [appeal to authority](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/21/Appeal-to-Authority) is a logical fallacy.

Comment: I can’t speak for the standard libraries, but it caused serious issues for frameworks that made heavy use of it, such as MFC. There’s a reason .NET doesn’t support it :)

Comment: @zzyz Actually, I've used several frameworks, such as the now defunct Reuters Triarch, that made very good use of MI - it's down tothe skill of the designers, really.

Comment: *implementations*, such as LLVM libc++ and GNU libstdc++, use multiple inheritance in about a dozen places, including inside an implementation detail of std::vector (what makes you think they "cannot" use it there?) Virtual inheritance - not so much, it's just the streams.

Answer (score 8):

iostream uses multiple and virtual inheritance; in particular, [`std::basic_iostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) inherits from `std::basic_istream` and `std::basic_ostream`, and both of them inherit from `std::basic_ios` (with virtual inheritance).

That being said, iostream is not widely regarded as an example of great design, so take this information at face value (= yes, the standard includes classes that use multiple and virtual inheritance), and not as a stamp of good practice.